# store two different classes (with same inherited base class) in same vector? (no boost)

Tags: c++, class, vector, copy

I have two different classes (First, Second) which inherit the same base class (Base).  I would like to store an instance of First and Second in the same vector, without their classes being spliced down to the Base class.  If I use vector, this splicing will occur, like following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {
  public:
    Base() { }
    virtual void test() { std::cout << "I am just the base class\n"; }
};

class First : public Base {
  public:
    First() { }
    void test() { std::cout << "This is the First class\n"; }
};

class Second : public Base {
  public:
    Second() { }
    void test() { std::cout << "This is the Second class\n"; }
};

int main() {
  First *f = new First();
  Second *s = new Second();

  // First, I keep a vector of pointers to their base class
  std::vector<Base> objs;
  objs.push_back(*f);
  objs.push_back(*s);
  objs[0].test();   // outputs "I am just the base class"
  objs[1].test();   // outputs "I am just the base class"
}
```

Ultimately, when the two objects are put in to vector, they are spliced.  Is there a way (without boost) to COPY both of these objects in to the same vector?  A vector is not what I am looking for, I want to copy the objects.

---

There were a lot of good answers here.  Unfortunately, I can't assume C++11, so I ended up leveraging the clone constructor with the hint at storing pointers.  But ultimately, the clone allows me to create the copy first.

Here was my final solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {
  public:
    Base() { }
    virtual void test() { std::cout << "I am just the base class\n"; }
    virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
};

class First : public Base {
  public:
    First() { }
    void test() { std::cout << "This is the First class\n"; }
    First* clone() const { return new First(*this); }
};

class Second : public Base {
  public:
    Second() { }
    void test() { std::cout << "This is the Second class\n"; }
    Second* clone() const { return new Second(*this); }
};

int main() {
  First *f = new First();
  Second *s = new Second();

  std::vector<Base *> bak;
  bak.push_back(f->clone());

  bak[0]->test();

}
```

Comment: I think you mean 'sliced'. 'Spliced' is kind of the opposite.

Comment: Just be sure that when using clone() without smart-pointers, to delete everything you cloned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy inherited objects without slicing, you need to define a clone() function in the base class and override in the derived classes:

```
class Base
{
public:
  Base* clone() const = 0;
}

class Derived
{  
  Derived* clone() const { return new Derived(*this); }
}
```

This way, even with a pointer to base class, you will get a copy of the derived class.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you create a `vector` of pointers to `Base`:

```
std::vector<Base*> objs;
```

or, better yet, a `vector` of smart pointers to the base class, so you don't need to worry about memory management.

Comment: I am looking to copy the objects, sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: @gnychis I don't understand. If you want to copy objects, have a copy constructor...

Comment: @gnychis: then deep copy the pointers.  Otherwise it cannot be done

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you want to copy the objects, but if it is for easy memory management then this will do :

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base> > objs;
objs.push_back(std::make_shared<First>());
objs.push_back(std::make_shared<Second>());
```

Comment: Note: std::make_shared is c++11 and not available in c++03

Comment: @mark: `std::shared_ptr` is also not available in C++03. The point is OP can solve his problem with a smart pointer. The namespace of the smart pointer is irrelevant. He can use `boost::` too.

Comment: @sad_man: The OP titled its post with "(no boost)".
And no, there is no std::shared_ptr in C++03 (apart some experimental extesions: shared_ptr has been ratified as "standard" in C++11, essentially by rewriting boost::shared_ptr using C++11 specific features)

Answer (score 2):

By the way you formulate the question, it is something impossible:
`vetor<Base>` holds a sequence of `Base`s, while `First` and `Second` are both `Base` plus something more.

By it's very nature, vector contains sequence of identical objects (all Base) and push_back, actually doesn't place the object inside the vector, but copies the object into the one that is constructed at the end of the vector (and is a `Base` object, hence only the `Base` subcomponent is copyed).

To solve the problem, you have to make your vector not to "contain" `Base`-s but to "refer to" Base-s. That requires pointers

```
std::vector<Base*> v;
v.push_back(new First);
v.push_back(new Second);
```

But this requires also memory management. This can be done in merely two ways:

1) use some smart-pointer that "owns" the base.
In C++11 there is `std::shared_ptr`, and `std::unique_ptr`.
In C++03 you have to arrange yourself a reference-counting pointer like

```
template<class T>
class ptr
{
public:
  ptr() :p(), c() {}
  explicit ptr(T* z) :p(z), c(new unsigned(1)) {}
  ptr(const ptr& s) :p(s.p), c(s.c) { if(c) ++*c; }
  ptr& operator=(const ptr& s) 
  { 
    if(this!=&s) 
    { 
      if(c && !--*c) { delete p; delete c; }
      p = s.p; c=s.c;
      if(c) ++*c;
    }
    return *this;
  }
  ~ptr() { if(c && !--*c) { delete p; delete c; } }

  T* operator->() const { return p; }
  T& operator*() const { return *p; }

private:
  T* p;
  unsigned* c; 
};
```

and declare your vector as

```
std::vector<ptr<Base> > v;
v.push_back(ptr(new First));
v.push_back(ptr(new Second));
v[0]->test();
v[1]->test();
```

Destroying `v`, will destroy the ptrs that will in turn destroy the objects.
**NOTE:** Base must also declare a **virtual destructor**, otherwise derived object cannot be plymorphically destroyed.

2)
Alternatively, you can "customize" the vector to "own" the pointer itself.
this can be obtained by something like

```
template<class T>
class owningvector: public std::vector<T*>
{
public:
  ~owningvector()
  {
    for(size_t i=0; i<size(); ++i)
      delete at(i);
  }
  owningvector() {}
private:
  //disable vector copy and assign
  owningvector(const owningvector&);
  owningvector& operator=(const owningvector&);
};

owningvector<Base> ov;
ov.push_back(new First);
ov.push_back(new Second);
```

**NOTE:** `Base` still need virtual destructor.
Also, being `std::vector` and `ownvector` not polymorphic on destruction, don't use themselves as polymorphic types.

3)
In case you are doing everything on_stack, you can very easily do

```
int main()
{
  First first;
  Second second;
  std::vector<Base*> v;
  v.push_back(&first);
  v.push_back(&second);

  v[0]->test();
  v[1]->test();

  //no other memory management is required:
  // v is destroyed without doing anything special.
  // second and first are destroyed just further.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

redifine copy constractor, then use :

```
std::vector<Base*> objs;
objs.push_back(new First(*f));
objs.push_back(new Second(*s));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm intreged by your saying that you want to copy your objects.
Generally, polymorphism and copy/assignment don't work well together,
but you can do it by using the letter-envelop idiom.  Something like:

```
class Base
{
    Base* myImpl;
    virtual Base* clone() const
    {
        //  or perhaps just abort, since this one shouldn't
        //  ever be called in practice.
        return new Base( myImpl->clone() );
    }
protected:
    Base() : myImpl( NULL ) {}
    Base( Base* impl ) : myImpl( impl ) {}

public:
    Base( Base const& other ) : myImpl( other.myImpl->clone() ) {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void test() { myImpl->test(); }
};

class First : public Base
{
    virtual Base* clone() const
    {
        return new First( *this );
    }

    First() {}
public:
    static Base createInstance() { return Base( new First ); }
    virtual void test() { std::cout << "In First" << std::endl; }
};

class Second : public Base
{
    virtual Base* clone() const
    {
        return new Second( *this );
    }

    Second() {}
public:
    static Base createInstance() { return Base( new Second ); }
    virtual void test() { std::cout << "In Second" << std::endl; }
};
```

This results in a class `Base` which behaves polymorphically, but
supports copy and assignment (and assignment may change the effective
type), and won't slice.  It also results in a serious performance hit,
and usually isn't what is wanted anyway—in my experience, most
polymorphic classes have identity, and shouldn't be copyable or
assignable.  But it is a possible solution, and can be useful in some
specific cases.