# c++ vector with inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

Reference code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Func {
public:
    virtual void call() {
        std::cout<< "Func -> call()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Foo : public Func {
public:
    void call() {
        std::cout<< "Foo -> call()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Bar : public Func {
public:
    void call() {
        std::cout<< "Bar -> call()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<Func> functors;

    functors.push_back( Func() );
    functors.push_back( Foo() );
    functors.push_back( Bar() );

    std::vector<Func>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = functors.begin(); iter != functors.end(); ++iter)
        (*iter).call();
}
```

When run that code, it produces the following output on my computer:

```
$ ./test
Func -> call()
Func -> call()
Func -> call()
```

Would there be any way to ensure that the correct virtual function is called in this instance? I'm new at C++ but my best guess is that here:

```
(*iter).call();
```

It's being cast to a `Func` object. Is this correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store two classes with the same base class in a std::vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777724/store-two-classes-with-the-same-base-class-in-a-stdvector)

Comment: yes, it is however I couldn't find that post before I created this one, sorry my search-fu must not be as good as yours sir

Comment: There is object slicing happening in your case, So the derived part is chipped off. You should be using Pointers of based class for Heterogenious Object Storage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a shared_ptr or unique_ptr to hold the elements of a collection of polymorphic type.

As your code is written now the Foo and Bar instances are cooerced (copy constructed) into an instance of type Func to fit into the vector.  (The reason is that vector stores its elements immediately by fixed-sized value for performance, however polymorphic subclasses are of a arbitrarily larger size unknown at compile-time, so it can only store the base class.)

This is better:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<shared_ptr<Func>> functors;

    functors.push_back( make_shared<Func>() );
    functors.push_back( make_shared<Foo>() );
    functors.push_back( make_shared<Bar>() );

    for (auto functor : functors)
        functor->call();
}
```

In the above a reference-counted pointer is used to implicitly share the hetrogeneous subclasses of Func in the vector.  (This indirection allows arbitrarily sized subclasses of Func to be stored by address indirection.)

Also, you may want to take a look at std::function and std::bind, rather than rolling your own functor type.

Another thing to look at would be perfect forwarding and varadic templates.

**update**: For old compiler:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<Func> > functors;

    functors.push_back( std::tr1::make_shared<Func>() );
    functors.push_back( std::tr1::make_shared<Foo>() );
    functors.push_back( std::tr1::make_shared<Bar>() );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < functors.size(); ++i)
        functors[i]->call();
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this code to compile, is this boost code or std c++? my compilers:


`i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00)

Apple clang version 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)`

Comment: @RonElliott: Sorry the code above is using the current C++ standard (2011).  I'll write a version with old standard, hang on.

Comment: @RonElliott: Ok update uses C++03+TR1, you should be able to use that with g++-4.2.  Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

the vector only holds the type `Func` by value, meaning that all your temporals `Foo` and `Bar` are sliced and casted to the base `Func` type

you need to change to something like `std::vector< Func* >` and dynamically allocate the derived classes instances in order for polymorphic dispatch to work

If you are completely sure that you won't pass this vector to other functions after this function returns, as an optimization you might want to allocate the instances in the stack:

```
std::vector< Func* > v;
Bar b;
Foo f;
v.push_back( &b);
v.push_back( &f);
```

Comment: This is working, yes I can be sure this vector won't be passed around so that is how I planned to implement

Answer (score 1):

your std::vector is storing Func objects - this means that when you call

```
functors.push_back( Foo() );
functors.push_back( Bar() );
```

you're creating `Foo` and `Bar` objects, then "slicing" those objects as they are copied into `Func` objects.

If you'd like to use Foo and Bar polymorphically, then a more typical pattern would be to store a vector of some pointer type (Preferably **not** "raw" pointers though), for example

`std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Func> >`

`std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Func> >`

Or, if you really have to.. (But only if you're using an older compiler which doesn't have shared_ptr or unique_ptr)

`std::vector< Func* >`

Answer (score 1):

In C++ polymorphism works only with pointers and references, while the vector stores directly instances of objects. When you call `push_back` the copy constructor of `Func` is called, which builds the `Func` object that is stored inside the vector.

This is called object slicing, you can learn more about it with a quick search in StackOverflow.

The solution would be to store pointers (or, even better, *smart* pointers) to your objects, which should be allocated elsewhere (probably on the heap).

Answer (score 1):

In general, instances of subclasses may be larger than those of their superclass, so you should not expect the subclasses to fit into your vector's slot.

And `push_back` probably will call internally a copy constructor (of the `Func` class, since you have `vector<Func>`) so the internal vector slots are indeed `Func` not of some other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have a vector of `Func`, but methods are called polymorphically only through references or pointers.

Answer (score 0):

there is a very simple way of making vector without using pointers by creating child class which will inherit Class A and Class B

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct BASE {
    string name = "Base class ";
};

struct A : BASE {
     string a = " class a ";
};

struct B : BASE {
     string b = " class b ";
};

struct C : A, B{
    //using base name from A or B// yeah is hardcoded
    string name = A::name;
};

int main()
{

    C c;
    c.a = "s";
    c.b = "h";
    vector<C> vec;

    vec.push_back(c);
    c.b = "j";
    vec.push_back(c);

    cout << vec[0].a << endl;
    cout << vec[0].b << endl;
    cout << vec[0].name << endl;

    cout << vec[1].a << endl;
    cout << vec[1].b << endl;
    cout << vec[1].name << endl;

    return 0;
}
```