# C++ inheritance: the virtual method of the derived class is not called

Tags: c++, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Store two classes with the same base class in a std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777724/store-two-classes-with-the-same-base-class-in-a-stdvector)

I have a Problem with inheritance in C++. Here I wrote a simple code to illustrate my problem:

```
//Animal.h
class Animal
{
public:

Animal();
~Animal();

virtual const void Eat();
};

//Bear.h
class Bear: public Animal
{
public:

Animal();
~Animal();

virtual const void Eat();
};

//Animal.cpp
const void Animal::Eat() {
}

//Bear.cpp
const void Animal::Eat() {
 //Do something
}
```

Now, in another class I declare a vector that should hold animals, and then I create a `Bear` and push it into my vector:

```
std::vector<Animal> a;
Bear b;
a.push_back(b);
```

The problem is now, that when I traverse my animal vector and try to call `Eat()`, the Eat method of the base class (animal) is called, but not the `Bear` `Eat` method.

Even trying with `dynamic_cast it` does not work: the `dynamic_cast` fails

```
dynamic_cast<Bear*>(&a.at(0));
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it because I lack copy constructor?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777724/store-two-classes-with-the-same-base-class-in-a-stdvector

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a vector that holds animal (smart) pointers instead.

A vector of objects suffers from **object slicing**.

I'm assuming the `void Animal::Eat()` in `Bear.cpp` is a typo, otherwise your code wouldn't compile.

Also, `const void`? You want to make sure you don't modify anything?

Comment: An interesting question would be if C++11 (where vector uses move semantics) still has this problem. Actually it should be "magically" fixed, I think. After all, no Animal should be copy-created then, but the Bear taken as is (including the vtable, presumably)?

Comment: @Damon that doesn't even come into question. When you declare `std::vector<Animal>` you explicitly say you want `Animal` objects. You'll no longer have Bears.

Comment: @Damon, try think how you will store it. (and how operator[] will be implemented)

Answer (score 1):

You need two things to enable polymorphism: virtual functions and pointers. You don't have pointers. Your `std::vector` must be a vector of `Animal*` (or std::unique_ptr in C++11), not `Animal`.

```
std::vector<Animal*> a;
Bear b;
a.push_back(b);
a[0] -> eat();
```

Then, your bear function `eat()` is with `Animal::`. Correct it.

In addiction, also the destructor must be virtual: destructors calls must be polymorphic as well.

Comment: I thouhgt about slicing problem but I did not expected that pointers will solve the problem. Thanks to all, I learned something new

Comment: But I am still curious, what happens when I put bear in animal vector? Does it call the base copy constructor and puts animal instead of bear?

Comment: @ISTB Bear IS an Animal (because of the inheritance relation). So if you put a Bear in Animal (and not Animal*) is like to make Animal a = b where b is a Bear: you can do this, but you copy in Animal only some information of Bear (the members they have in common). Sincerely, I don't know if in this case it is called only the constructor of Animal or if it is called the constructor of Bear and then we have a partial copy of Bear in Animal as I said. The result is the same: you don't have a Bear but an Animal: so eat() of Animal is called.

Comment: Yes, I think that first the Animal constructor is called and then the copy constructor which of course copies only "animal" information of bear but not bears information