# Are there real use cases for smart pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I was reading about smart pointers in C++ and I am surprised that more than 99% of the given examples are in fact fairly bad examples because in those cases dynamic allocation could be avoided. I would agree to use smart pointers only in the context that STL containers wouldn't work. For instance in dynamic arrays (`std::vector`) performance matters so it is perhaps better to have well-tested code without any use of smart pointers.

Here what I consider a bad example because in this case `unique_ptr` isn't the solution, but stack allocation would be the proper way.

```
MyObject* ptr = new MyObject(); 
ptr->DoSomething(); 
delete ptr;
```

So what could be good examples or uses for Smart Pointers in C++?

Said differently what design pattern would require to transfer the ownership of a pointer to another object?

Comment: the premise is of course that you need to dynamically allocate something. I never saw anybody suggesting to replace automatic storage with a smart pointer managed object

Comment: The internet is full with examples and many SO threads as well, can you be more specific?

Comment: the question reads like a rant btw, I don't really understand what you are asking

Comment: for example you can find lots of questions on SO about storing polymorphic objects in containers. The correct answer is almost always to use smart pointers

Comment: Related: [What is move semantic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics) [When to use smart pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

Comment: @TonyTannous I didn't find good use of smart pointers on Google or SO. All questions about `What is the use of smart pointers` give examples that would be better  written without any use of dynamic allocation.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Just give me one single example and I will admit my question is dumb.

Comment: I just gave you one: Store polymorphic objects in a `std::vector`

Comment: You were already given a good example: storing polymorphic objects in containers

Comment: Another: factory pattern with polymorphic types

Comment: I am confused by some of your statements, eg " it is perhaps better to have well-tested code without any use of smart pointers."  smart pointers are well tested. We had a fail with `auto_ptr` but now smart pointers are well settled in C++, suggesting that they are not well tested is a bit odd

Comment: Another one: storing non-moving, non-copyable objects in `std::vector`

Comment: @bolov I guess it is where I need help. Storing polymorphic objects into containers would be `vector.push_back(new Derived())`. If the object is removed from the vector, then it would be deleted. I don't see any use for smart-pointers here.

Comment: "If the object is removed from the vector, then it would be deleted" no. I suggest you to study the basics before complaining about the advanced...

Comment: @idclev463035818 Smart pointers are well tested, but they add overhead. So if you want to release a self-contained data container, you would certainly prefer to use regular pointers if you can make sure there is no way of memory leak.

Comment: Another one: storing objects to which you need persistent references, even when the object is moved (even when the container moves it)

Comment: dynamic memory allocation is overhead. Using a smart pointer in that case does not add overhead. No offense, but you seem to have some misconceptions

Comment: @idclev463035818 In my understanding keeping track of references with a count object does add some overhead.

Comment: if you do not use a smart pointer you need some other means to keep track of the lifetime of the object. That has a cost and is error prone. Smart pointers have proven to be a good solution to a common problem

Comment: `unique_ptr` has no overhead over `new`, and is the default smart pointer

Comment: @idclev463035818, my bad I wanted to write `vector.push_back(Derived())`

Comment: @nowox thats even worse. Give me a second, I will try to find an example of what i was talking about above

Comment: there are many questions about that issue, this is a good one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777724/store-derived-class-objects-in-base-class-variables

Comment: `vector.push_back(Derived())` would result in [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am surprised that more than 99% of the given examples are in fact fairly bad examples because in those cases dynamic allocation could be avoided

This is probably because the examples are intended to be super-simple.

> So what could be good examples or uses for Smart Pointers in C++?

Never mind "goodness", but consider the following examples of cases where they're relevant:

#### 1. When you can't hold on to the stack

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T[]> print_and_allocate(std::size_t n)
{
    std::cout << "Allocating " << n << " elements of size " << sizeof(T) << '\n';
    return std::make_unique<T[]>(n);
}
```

you can't perform the allocation on the stack, because you're returning before your allocated element is used. Also, you can't just return a single constructed or an `std::array`, because the number of elements to allocate is not known in advance.

#### 2. A need to refer to one of several possible subclasses

```
class A;
class B : public A { /* ... */ };
class C : public A { /* ... */ };

// ...

auto my_a = std::unique_ptr<A>(condition ? (A*) new B : (A*) new C);
my_a.some_virtual_method();
```

#### 3. Complex de-allocation logic

A pointer doesn't tell you when/how it needs to be freed/deallocated. You can make a simple assumption ("I need to free the pointer I get from this function"), but this already suggests expressing your assumption in a wrapper class. If the conditions for de-allocation are more complex, and especially if the pointer recipient isn't aware of them, it becomes critical that they be communicated somehow. An `std::shared_ptr` or `std::weak_ptr` are two ways to do so; and another is an `std::unique_ptr` with a [custom deleter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

#### 4. When future usability not guaranteed

When the provider of the pointer can't guarantee it will continue to be valid, but expects that it likely will be - you need some kind of wrapper class to reflect that fact and to make sure you don't try to dereference the pointer when you actually can't. This is where `std::weak_ptr()` comes into play.

---

More generally: If you needed to allocate memory and hold a pointer before, for some reason, and couldn't make do without it - you most-probably want to switch to using a smart pointer instead. See also:

[What is a smart pointer and when should I use one (answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30143936/1593077).

Comment: In your example you can return an `std::vector` and it would be automatically deleted. No need for `unique_ptr`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @nowox: No, you're not wrong. But consider my general point: If what you want is an `std::vector`, you would not have used a pointer in the first place.

Comment: @nowox if your class is non-copyable and non-moveable, you can't put it into vector. Also since unique_ptr doesn't have all the functionality of vector, it may have less overhead in case you don't need vector's capabilities anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> So what could be good examples or uses for Smart Pointers in C++?

Any situation where you need to have a ressource on the heap.

You are right that most smart pointer examples would be written with a stack allocation in a real world scenario. But they are just that - simple examples to demonstrate the use/advantages of smart pointers.

In reality however, you can't place everything on the stack. And once you need dynamic memory allocation on the heap a smart pointer is almost always a better choice than a raw pointer with new/delete.

Comment: "You are right that most smart pointer examples..." this was already mentioned in the question with zero evidence and repeating it still does not convince me, just saying

Comment: @idclev463035818 Convince you to what? That a lot of textbook/tutorial code snippets don't show code in a real world scenario and instead use a minimal example? For example just take the cppreference entry about smart pointers: [Link](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers). This is what the op is talking about. In reality you would never use a pointer, smart or not, for an local int inside of my_func(). It is just used here to demonstrate how the use of a smart pointer can help to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: all I am saying is that OP is writing "99%", you write "most" and I don't see that. I just checked the first 7 smart pointer examples I found online. 2 of them are poor in the sense that they use a scenario where you wouldn't use dynamic allocation in the first place. 2 out of 7 is neither "most" nor 99%. 7 is of course too little statistics to make a general statement, but its more than none. Sorry I am a bit picky sometimes. I just don't see that it is most examples

Comment: the first example on that cppref site is btw quite poor, I agree ;)

Answer (score 0):

In real use cases you actually don't want to care about memory management. You don't want memory leaks because you forget one `delete` somewhere. Thats where smart pointers come in handy, since they lift the responsibility to clean up from you.

Comment: If I don't want to care about memory management I would probably use a high-level language, not C++. When I use C/C++ it is because I have hard constraints such as limited memory or limited CPU time.

Comment: @nowox using manual new/delete does not help you with memory limit or cpu time. `unique_ptr` is literally a zero-cost abstraction.

Comment: I partially agree for `unique_ptr` since you still have the cost of one indirection. It is worth it on most of use-cases, but can be an issue on certain embedded real-time targets.