# Fill an array with different classes which all inherit from the same class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, subclass, stdvector

My situation looks something like this:

```
class Parent;

class Child1 : public Parent;
class Child2 : public Parent;

class ChildOfChild1 : public Child1;


std::vector<std::vector<Parent>> matrix;
```

I want to be able to contain all the classes within this one matrix but I am not sure of the best way to do it.

Right now if left as it is every Child I add to the matrix just gets converted into a Parent with all the methods and variables not contained in the Parent removed.

I know something like this should be possible in Java which is also strictly typed so I thought I might ask if it is also possible in C++.

Comment: You get what you want in Java because Java defaults to reference semantics when dealing with class instances. C++ defaults to value semantics. Instead of storing references to a `Parent` or `Parent`-derived value, C++ will store a `Parent` directly unless you explicitly ask for a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777724/store-derived-class-objects-in-base-class-variables)

The thing you want to use is called **[Object Slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)**
Try this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Parent*>> matrix
```

Comment: Good eyes. That duplicate was just what I was looking for.